# How to get the matching tables for a particular column name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I want to find all the matching list of tables where the columnname = 'Letter'?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,
       TABLE_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'Letter'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME = 'Letter'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  select 
  type_desc,
  sch.name as 'schema name',
  obj.name as 'table', 
  col.name as columnname,
  ty.name as  columntype,
  col.max_length as columnmaxlength,
  is_identity
  from  sys.objects obj 
  inner join sys.all_columns col
  on obj.object_id = col.object_id
  inner join sys.schemas sch
  on obj.schema_id = sch.schema_id
  inner join sys.types ty
  on col.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id 
 where type ='U'
 and col.name like '%letter%'
 order by type_desc,sch.name, obj.name, col.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Above code will get you TABLES as well as VIEWS
To rule out VIEWS

```
SELECT C.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
WHERE C.TABLE_NAME=T.TABLE_NAME AND C.COLUMN_NAME = 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME'
AND T.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```